# Incorrect Syntax near 's. Unclosed quotation mark after the character string

Tags: vb.net

i got an error when i want to save misspelled words in the database .
For Ex. If i want to save "Childrens books" As "Children's books" i got an error at 's .
error:incorrect syntax near 's. unclosed quotation mark.
I i put like "Children''s books" and execute in sql server it works fine but when i want read data dynamically with tem variable using .net i didn't get results.

I got an error when I wanted to save misspelled words in the database .
For Ex. If i want to save "Childrens books" As "Children's books" i got an error at 's .

error:incorrect syntax near 's. unclosed quotation mark.

If I put something like "Children' 's books" and execute it in sql server it works fine but when i want to read data dynamically with temp variable using vb.net i didn't get results.

Note: Other words are saved perfectly when I don't have single quote words.
take an ex. words like, USource=Amazon and UDescription=Children's book,UItemID=71

***vb.net***

UDescription =gvInsuredData.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("DescriptionProperty").Value.ToString()

USource = gvInsuredData.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("SourceProperty").Value.ToString()

UItemID = gvInsuredData.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value

command = New SqlCommand("update tblProperty set personalPropertyDescription='" & UDescription & "', personalPropertySource='" & USource & "' where ClaimID = " & ClaimID & " and personalPropertyItemID=" & UItemID & " ", objcnn)

command.ExecuteNonQuery()

---

Comment: Build your command string using parameters.

Comment: Because single quotes are used to denote literal text, including a single quote in literal text requires escaping it with another single quote. You'd only do that if you were actually writing out that literal text though, which you're not. If you always use parameters to insert values into SQL code then you avoid this issue and many others, most critically SQL injection, which could allow a malicious user to corrupt or even delete your entire database. There's loads of information around about using parameters with ADO.NET, so you should look it up.

Answer (score 0):

Below code Works for my Question

***vb.net answer***

```
  UDescription = gvInsuredData.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("DescriptionProperty").Value.ToString()

  UItemID = gvInsuredData.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value

            USource = gvInsuredData.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("SourceProperty").Value.ToString()

           
            command = New SqlCommand("update tblInsuredPersonalProperty set personalPropertyDescription=@Description, personalPropertySource=@Source where ClaimID = @Claimid and personalPropertyItemID=@itemId ", objcnn)

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", UDescription)

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Source", USource)

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Claimid", ClaimID)

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemId", UItemID)

            command.ExecuteNonQuery()

            objcnn.Close()
```

---

Comment: Just so that you're aware: https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/

Comment: Yes ,@Mr.Andrew Mortimer